# Change size of embedded google doc

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website for my first client and I'm having trouble figuring out how to change the size and background colour for an embedded google doc. any help would be very much appreciated.
here is a link to my github with the code https://github.com/TheCrimsonLord/Website

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring to the google doc iframe as seen below

```
<iframe class="list" src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vRHBRjfZSJaZVq3CGR_mKgzF9ubC7ElGTvAy9j8CBpXt1nJrpbB-_V2_wMHeTCB6i4xsZVcgsykZRRu/pub?embedded=true"></iframe>
```

If so, changing the width and height can be done using the **height** and **width** attributes as so:

```
<iframe width="1000px" height="800px" class="list" src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vRHBRjfZSJaZVq3CGR_mKgzF9ubC7ElGTvAy9j8CBpXt1nJrpbB-_V2_wMHeTCB6i4xsZVcgsykZRRu/pub?embedded=true"></iframe>
```

However, manipulating or even styling contents **inside** an iframe is not possible.

Comment: Thank you soo much, been stuck on this for an hour

Comment: and now I'm struggling to change the background colour

Comment: You want to change the colour of the actual doc? Impossible to style contents of an iframe. Best to change the actual page colour in the document in page format, then linking it